# Increase AuthSession using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, api

I need your help that I am using servicestack for api used in mobile app. We have our own auth provider but the problem is that if we do not do any activities on mobile to call the api then session expires after 30 mins and user is logout from the mobile app. I need help that how i can increase this session timeout to 5 days or more.

The following is the version of the stackservice i used in the project.

```
 <package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.56" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="3.9.56" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Host.AspNet" version="3.9.33" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="3.9.56" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="3.9.57" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="3.9.56" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way to control [Session](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) lifetimes in ServiceStack is by intercepting each time a Session is saved and change what Session Expiry it's saved with by overriding `OnSaveSession` in your `AppHost`, so you can specify Sessions to last for **5 days** with:

```
public override void OnSaveSession(
    IRequest httpReq, IAuthSession session, TimeSpan? expiresIn = null)
{
    base.OnSaveSession(httpReq, session, TimeSpan.FromDays(5));
}
```

Note: sessions are saved in the registered [Caching Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching) which by default uses the `MemoryCacheClient` to save sessions in Memory where all Authenticated Sessions will be lost if the App Server restarts. You can persist sessions across App restarts by configuring to use any of the other [distributed Caching Providers](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. Tomorrow i will check in my morning this solution and will update accordingly

Comment: The solution you provided is not working as the library i am using is older one and the override method is not supported. I am using 2.050 version of servicestack, do you know any other solution.

Comment: @user3604950 There's no [v2.0.5 of ServiceStack on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack), if you know the real version you can browse the [source code at each release](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/releases) and look to see if there's any Expiry property option available on `SessionFeature`.

Comment: I have checked the SessionFeature, no Expiry property is available.

Comment: serviceStack version i updated in question part. Any solution do you know for this version.